# SQL Server Compact 4 Startup - LoadNativeBinaries Slow

Tags: sql-server-ce, database-performance

We are trying to switch an application that serializes data into files to use a database. This is a basic windows form application.

I noticed on start-up of our application that there is significant lag when initializing the database connection through Entity Framework. I have no idea what would be causing this and my Google skills are failing me.

I did a dotTrace performance profile on this and this is what it showed:

[image: LoadNativeBinaries lag]

The performance profile shows almost 14 seconds of SQL Server CE running the `LoadNativeBinaries`. What am I missing? How do I speed this up?

**UPDATE**

I created a test database project and deployed it to the device I am testing on. The first time I ran the test program, it took about 17 seconds. After the first time, it took less than a second. I then tried running my actual application and the lag has disappeared. I reinstalled my application, and the first time I ran the application, it took 17 seconds, but subsequent runs took less than a second. This is different to my original issue where it took 10+ seconds every launch.

I've uploaded the test project I am using [here](http://tomsfreelance.com/databaseTest.zip). I'm curious if anyone else gets similar results.

The following is the config file I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="dataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/data.csdl|res://*/data.ssdl|res://*/data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string='Data Source=&quot;data.sdf&quot;'"
            providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

and the test program:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data.EntityClient;

namespace databaseTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string _connectionString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Configuration exeConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("databaseTest.exe");
            _connectionString = exeConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["dataEntities"].ConnectionString;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
            st.Start();
            EntityConnection ec = new EntityConnection(_connectionString);
            dataEntities ent = new dataEntities(ec);
            st.Stop();

            connectionTime.Text = st.Elapsed.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS platform is in use (OS and Service Pack)?

This is usually caused by either 
1 ) invalid Access Control List in the RSA certificate folder or 
2 ) invalid Internet proxy configuration.

**1)** Can be fixed by [resetting the ACL](http://lallousx86.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/resetting-ntfs-files-security-and-permission-in-windows-7/) (it is broken even for administrators)

> To reset all the files permissions, type:
>
> icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET

**2)** Can be fixed by correcting the proxy configuration, or disabling Certificate Revocation Lists checks via a [registry key](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458982.aspx).

> To disable CRL checking, create a registry setting at the following
>   location:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Sstpsvc\parameters
>   The setting must be a DWORD value named NoCertRevocationCheck. Set the
>   value to 1.

Comment: This is on Windows 7 Professional SP 1. This happens on all the devices I have tested locally with. I've looked into both of your solutions and I'm not sure of the proper steps to complete these. Do you have a reference I could look at? This also does NOT happen when I use the Visual Studio debugger. Only when I have packaged and deployed the application. Could it have to do with signing? My exe's are all signed, but I haven't signed the database file.

Comment: Looks like this may be causing problems as well: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2677070

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, this is caused by the issue of moving from one paltform to another, described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2009/04/01/after-moving-the-database-from-one-platform-to-other-the-first-sqlceconnection-open-takes-more-time.aspx

Comment: It looks like there is no way around this one then.

Comment: Only workaround is to preopen the file on a matching platform, or supply a database file per platform

Comment: Perhaps this answer isn't the issue then? My PC is a Windows 7 Professional SP1 PC and the devices (Panasonic Toughbooks) are also Windows 7 Professional SP1.

Comment: I will work on pre-opening it shortly. (Even though it was created on Win7SP1)

Comment: Different OS language?

Comment: Pre-opening the file and then including it in the installer had no effect.

Comment: Does it make sense that removing `<remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>` would get rid of this lag? How important is this tag? All systems are going to be set up exactly the same way.

Comment: This appears to be the result of a CRL request going out on first launch. On our test environment, the request is not authorized by the network and takes a long time to start. (Request was for crl.microsoft.com)

Comment: As I said in my initial reply - just posted this, btw FAQ: Why is opening my SQL Server Compact database slow? http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/08/faq-why-is-opening-my-sql-server.html

Comment: I previously tried your solution below and following the steps again from your link in the comment above, the crl request goes away, but I still get hang for two different requests - one for `ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/disalloedcertstl.cab` and `watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/Generic/AppHangB1/appStuffHere...`